# Faster with lookup object list rather than objects in table?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm making a particle simulation with sand and all those, which involves finding the attributes of cells many. many.. many... times every step.

I have a list of materials containing objects with values like density and color, and the grid of cells is stored in a table of objects, with the cell `id` corresponding to which material:

```js
var mats = [
  { name: 'sand', density: 100 },
  { name: 'water', density: 50 },
// ...
];
```

A cell object would look something like this: `{ id: 1, temp: 32, /* ... */ }`, 
And every lookup of the density of a cell looked like this: `mats[grid[x][y].id].density`



However, I thought it would be quicker to code and possibly faster to instead store every value inside the cell object.

So a cell object would be given its material values: `{ id: 1, temp: 32, name: 'sand', density: 100, /* ... */ }`
And every lookup of the density of cell would instead be: `grid[x][y].density`

BUT, when I ran the simulation, it nearly slowed to a halt!

`mats[grid[x][y].id].density` ran almost twice as quickly as `grid[x][y].density` when I simulated the lookups!

What's going on here? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Here is a "minimal" reproducible example of the problem:

**Edit #2:**
I changed the test to loop through more of the grid using `Math.floor(i/40)%40` and make the ids random, and now the disparity is waaay bigger!

```js
var grid = []; // grid of squares 50x50
var mats = [
{ // 0
    name: 'air',
    density: 5, // densities kg/m^3 (not always legit)
    step: (x, y) => {
        
    },
    type: 3,
    data: (x, y) => { return {}; },
    color: (x, y) => 0/*{ let c = 20+rNum(3)*5; return [c,c,c]; }*/,
    singleColor: [0,0,0],
    cond: 0.7,
    startTemp: -1
},
{ // 1
    name: 'brick',
    density: Infinity,
    step: (x, y) => {

    },
    type: 0,
    data: (x, y) => { return {}; },
    color: (x, y) => 0/*((x+Math.floor(y/3)*3)%5==0||y%3==0?[200,200,200]:[200, 0, 0])*/,
    singleColor: [200,0,0],
    cond: 0.1,
    startTemp: -1
},
{ // 2
    name: 'sand',
    density: 2082,
    step: (x, y) => {

    },
    type: 1,
    data: (x, y) => { return {}; },
    color: (x, y) => 0/*[250,240-rNum(4)*15,0]*/,
    singleColor: [250,230,0],
    cond: 0.15,
    startTemp: -1
},
];



grid = [];
for (let x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
    grid.push([]);
    for (let y = 0; y < 500; y++) {
                        let id = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            grid[x].push({
                //...mats[id],
                id: id,
                graved: false,
                pushedUp: false,
                timer: 0,
                color: mats[id].color(x, y),
                temp: 20,
                data: mats[id].data(x, y),
            });
    }
}

console.log('Using mats[grid[x][y].id].density:');
console.time();
var test;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    test = mats[grid[i%40][Math.floor(i/40)%40].id].density;
console.timeEnd();


grid = [];
for (let x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
    grid.push([]);
    for (let y = 0; y < 500; y++) {
            let id = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            grid[x].push({
                ...mats[id],
                id: 0,
                graved: false,
                pushedUp: false,
                timer: 0,
                color: mats[id].color(x, y),
                temp: 20,
                data: mats[id].data(x, y),
            });
    }
}
console.log('Using grid[x][y].density:');
console.time();
var test;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    test = grid[i%40][Math.floor(i/40)%40].density;
console.timeEnd();
```

Comment: With small data set you may not see the difference, try using a large data set and then compare

Comment: The grid is around 200x200, so a lotta cells. And every material has around 10 values, some of them functions.

Comment: You mentioned: "mats[grid[x][y].id].density ran almost twice as quickly as grid[x][y].density".
I'm interested in how you came to this conclusion? Is there any chance that you included the processing and storing of the extra value inside each cell object in this performance test?

Comment: This type of micro-benchmark is almost completely useless as it can be completely optimized away (and indeed, if I change the grid size to 200x200, accessing density directly is a tad faster, unless I swap the order of the test, in which case it's a tad slower. It's not clear how this is a "reproducible example" since the timing differs by only ~5-15ms if I make clicky on "Run code snippet".